# Woocommerce and Gravity Forms problem with deliveries

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, gravity

It's been a week since I'm trying to resolve this, and I'm just stuck. Please help :)

Here is the problem: I have a website with catering services, that are delivered every day to the clients. It's done using wordpress, gravity forms + addons (woocommerce and perk plugins with calendar and conditional pricing) with complicated conditional logic as the meals have different calories and so on. It's only one product, but it's coming from Gravity Forms itself. The form is calculating the number of days as a hidden field and I want to calculate the delivery cost by multiplying the number of days, that the Client placed the order for by the flat rate cost of a particular delivery zone in woocommerce (3 zones with different delivery costs in total). Let's say the cost of the delivery to one City is $5 and the order is placed for 10 meals, meaning 10 deliveries with fresh meal every day - so I want the delivery cost to be $5*10 = $50 for that order. I tried to achieve this with Gravity Perks- not possible, with Woocommerce Addon for Gravity Forms- it's possible to override the number of items ordered, but not the delivery cost itself... and I'm out of ideas :(

Does anybody have any clue how to achieve this?
Huge Thanks and a big beer in advance :)

Comment: Can you give more info?  Can you provide a link to the product page?

Comment: Sure. It's in polish - but the ordering system is very clear.

Comment: www.vitalbox-catering.pl

Comment: Maybe this is silly, but can you collect their delivery address on the gravity form so you can calculate the charge in one place? You'd then have to remove the delivery charge you currently have set up on the checkout page.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it's great, but will Gravity Form be able to recognize locations? As every location has different delivery cost- depending upon the distance. So the Form will have to be able to recognize the post codes -as regular Woocommerce does. You think that's possible within GF itself?

Comment: I have done something similar using Populate Anything. You can create another form called shipping zones.  You can add a field for minimum postal code, maximum postal code, region and delivery charge.  Then add an entry for each region, ie https://postal-codes.cybo.com/poland/  Then when someone enters their postal code, you can use Populate anything to pull the delivery charge if the code is between the min and max postal code from an entry. Make sense?

Comment: How can I thank you? I'm not an "every-day" stackoverflow user, I was trying to increase your reputation... am I "to newbie" to do it?

Comment: Consider me thanked.  If my husband and I ever make it to Poland, I'll take you up on that beer : )

Comment: Consider it done :)